# Magento chage price - phpMyAdmin

Tags: database

I change my price using this code:

```
update`catalog_product_index_price` 
set price = price + price*0.15;
```

He change, but after 10-30 miuntes he return me the old pices

Comment: Product price saved in catalog_product_entity_decimal table. Attribute id 77. I have checked in Magento 2.1.6. You have use index table. After update price run indexing command, clear catch and check on front end.